# Loop through Brushes in Silverlight to get all possible colors

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, brushes

I have a class that worked on a previous project i had that looped through all the available colors in the WPF application, this is shown below;

```
public class ListOfColors
    {
        public List<ComboBoxItem> SelectableColours;
        private PropertyInfo[] _propInfo;
        public List<ComboBoxItem> GetListOfColours()
        {
            List<ComboBoxItem> SelectableColours = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
            Type brushesType = typeof(Brushes);

            PropertyInfo[] colors = brushesType.GetProperties();
            _propInfo = colors;


            foreach (var color in colors)
            {
                ComboBoxItem colour = new ComboBoxItem();
                colour.Content = color.Name;
                SelectableColours.Add(colour);
            }

            return SelectableColours;
        }
    }
```

This works fine with my WPF application but now i am trying to replicate the same thing in a silverlight project but it is saying im missing a using directive or assembly reference. I have tried to add the `System.Windows.Media` reference but it still says that im missing it.

Is there a step i am missing or do i have to get a different Type back, I have tried to use the `Colors` as a type but this brings back a limited number of colors, 15 in total;

```
Type brushesType = typeof(Colors);
```

Comment: There is no `Brushes` class in Silverlight.

Comment: http://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/translating-c-brushes-to-silverlight-brushes/

Comment: As for WPF you don't need to use reflection.  You can use `var allBrushes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Brushes)).Cast<Brushes>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight does not have a `Brushes` class, and as you note, the `Colors` class has a limited number.

I suggest you make your own version of `Colors` that has everything.

See: http://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/translating-c-color-to-silverlight-color/